# Database capacity when changing varchar length (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database

Recently I was changed collation from `latin1` to `utf8`.
And there is an error of length because `utf8` has longer size.
Before changing collation the field type was `varchar(50)` and now I'm going to extend to `varchar(255)`.
In this case, would the capacity of database extended as well which might be occur error of db capacity limit.

Also if I insert record including that field which is smaller than `varchar(255)`, would it take full `varchar(255)` capacity?

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

No according to the MYSQL website https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

with varchar the actual storage is allocated dynamically and is only determined by the number of characters you store into it.

it's not that straight cut though take VARCHAR(255) and VARCHAR(500), even if you put 1 character inside such column. The value appended at the end of the row will be an integer that stores what the actual length of the stored data.

So in the case of VARCHAR(255) it will be additional 1 byte, VARCHAR(500) it will be 2 bytes.

Its a minor difference.

I believe, though i have no data to back it up, that the shorter the varchar length the better the index lookup  performance

Comment: Then why has it length parameter like varchar(255) or varchar(500)? is there problem without size indicated? what is the difference? only has different limitation?

Comment: mysql supports varchar(max) however, putting a size in there helps mysql to 'know' about the data for optimisations, indexing etc

Comment: i have been doing a little reading and i found this on a previous post. - Actually access wise it makes a huge difference, since when MySql creates the result set in memory it turns it into a matrix, thus if your largest field is 16 characters, but the field is defined as 128 characters you have to allocate an extra 112 characters for every row. This wastes a lot a memory. – Kris Erickson Jul 20, i don,t know if that is true, but it makes sense, i also don't know if it is determined by the largest field data length added, or the size set in the varchar.